# Accessing my 'Options' panel from another script

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've created a pong clone with the following:
Main Menu (New Game, Options, About, Quit).
Level1 (Able to press ESC which opens a pause menu panel (Resume Game, Options, Quit to Main Menu).

So far I've duplicated my Options Panel from the Main Menu scene, and pasted it in the Level1 scene. Is there a better way to do it? Can I call the Main Menu Options panel from my Level1 scene? I guess creating an Options prefab would be another idea?

I would like to get it sorted before I work on my options menu (Sound ON/OFF, Sound adjustable via slider, Music ON/OFF, Music adjustable via slider) - hopefully I can implement it so it covers all scenes.

This is in C# by the way, in Unity.

Comment: options canvas prefab is the best idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not change values in other scene directly as the instances do not exist at that moment but you can use PlayerPrefs to save data on exiting scene and at the loading of scene you can load that data in you UI.

For example you can save and load sound volume like this:

```
float mySoundVolume;

void OnDestroy(){
   PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("SoundVolume", mySoundVolume);
}
void Awake(){
   mySoundVolume = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("SoundVolume");
   applyValuesToUI();
}
```

You can read more about PlayerPrefs here. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.GetFloat.html

Comment: Awesome, thanks man! I guess this is how they carry over your points etc when you start a new level (scene)?

Comment: Yeah, pretty much. This is definitely easiest way to do it. If you are looking for more advanced saving of user data (eg. option to easily pass it over network, to save some more advanced data types) you can look into this asset https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/768
(You can prolly find something much cheaper or even free that fits your needs but I have experience with this one and can vouch for it). It works pretty much like PlayerPrefs but with more options. You should either way learn PlayerPrefs first, always useful to know if you are working on something simple.